# Should I comment or just downvote?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, comments

I'm noticing that when I downvote some users with a comment, I get a `-2`(downvote) to my answer within 2 minutes.

And the answer is a recent one, with upvotes on it. (I'm confirming that my answer was useful)

So, I am starting to believe that the users whom I downvoted with a comment are going through my profile and downvoting me.

So, should I stop giving comments when I downvote someone?

Comment: There are *some* that want to make [commenting mandatory when downvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251226/eliminate-anonymous-downvoting)... You are experiencing one of the main reasons why *that* is a bad idea.

Comment: are you sure, is it `-2` or `-1`?

Comment: @Praveen yes. I'm sure. I get `-1` when I downvote someone

Comment: @Praveen: When your own post is downvoted, you lose 2 points. When you downvote someone else's *answer*, you lose 1 point.

Comment: I don't actually see any downvotes on your profile I can correlate to a comment you left; make sure you don't jump to conclusions about whom voted, either. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I didn't jump to conclusion. I was "starting to believe" ;)

Comment: @AmitJoki: I didn't say you did. :-) I said "make sure you don't". :-P

Comment: @MartijnPieters, I remember that, bcuz in my previous previous question, you had advised me on the same ;)

Comment: Random note regarding one of your recent said comments (although I'm guessing that that's not the one you're talking about) - you seemingly downvoted someone's answer because of one of their comments on *your* answer, which isn't particularly appropriate - you should vote on content, not users (if a post is useful, upvote it, if it's not, downvote it - who posted it or what else they posted shouldn't matter), even if it's difficult to stick to this sometimes. I assume the comment you're talking about was deleted.

Comment: @Dukeling, I'm not talking about that comment. But the comment you are speaking is correct. He accused me of copying his content and so downvoted me. And I downvoted him with a comment that "I have no need to copy you answer. Don't make assumptions"

Comment: Usually if I think a competing answer has flaws, I write a comment without downvoting, leaving the other answerer a chance to change the answer or justify the relevant part. Then if the user does not react to my comment I downvote a bit later. This seems to avoid some people's need for revenge

Comment: @AmitJoki - so your question is complaining about people making "revenge downvotes", and then in a comment under that question, you admit making a revenge downvote  yourself.  This makes it difficult to take your complaint seriously.

Comment: @NiklasB.  An answer "having flaws" is not a sufficient reason for a downvote.  Downvotes should be reserved for answers that are actively misleading - that do more harm than good.

Comment: @DavidWallace From a community management standpoint, it behooves us to take the complaint even more seriously, if even the complainants are participating in the problem.

Comment: @WarrenDew Being misleading would classify as a flaw, in my opinion. Still I believe in benefit of the doubt, maybe the author just didn't realize that they expressed themselves ambiguously or in a confusing way, or that their code or algorithm does not work at all etc.

Comment: @NiklasB. Being misleading certainly counts as a flaw.  However, there are plenty of flaws that fall short of being misleading, and don't justify a downvote even if not corrected.

Comment: @WarrenDew Your point being? I didn't say anything about what flaws I consider worth downvoting, so you are arguing to no avail

Comment: @NiklasB. Your earlier comment reads as if you will downvote any answer that "has flaws", if the writer "does not react to [your] comment", implying that you consider all flaws worth downvoting if not corrected.

Comment: @WarrenDew From the context it is pretty obvious that I meant answers having flaws that are worthy of a downvote (because the discussion is about downvotes)

Comment: It wasn't obvious to me.

Comment: Well then, I stand corrected

Comment: @DavidWallace, I admit taking your so called "revenge", for sure. But what would you do in case someone downvotes you and the downvoter comments that he downvoted your post since you have plagiarized his answer, and you know that your answer clearly solves OP's problem?

Comment: I'd ignore him.

Comment: @DavidWallace, really????

Comment: Upvotes and downvotes are for indicating the quality of questions and answers, not for implementing personal vendettas.

Comment: @DavidWallace, yeah, but I can't stand someone downvoting my correct answer. It is okay if you do ignore it, but I can't. Also, you should have seen the comments below, after which he undoed his downvote, and I undoed my downvote. So there is no point in talking about my taking a "revenge", when, both took out our downvotes after solving the issue by comments

Comment: @AmitJoki I felt the same when I started on SO, but if you think about it, it's really not worth your time. Even if you care about reputation (which I do), the -2 is barely noticable. The only problem is that you might get rated below other answers, but that often resolves itself if your answer is indeed the best one. I've had heated situations like yours as well and usually tried to resolve the personal element in a way similar to how you did, but I later realized it was not worth it to begin with

Comment: @NiklasB., will remember this piece of advice from now. Thanks ;)

Comment: I have this terrible urge to down vote this question for no reason and not leave a comment. (:

Comment: why not both! http://img.4plebs.org/boards/tg/image/1395/89/1395891454236.png

Comment: Comment along with the downvote. I hate it when people downvote my posts without explaining what's wrong with it. The way I see it, if you are not going to be helpful and explain what's wrong with the post, keep your mouth shut.

Comment: Downvoting is evil. I never downvote. Almost. If I like I upvote, if i don't like I just go away (unless it's spam - then I flag).

Comment: I couldn't agree any less. Downvoting without a comment is especially evil but downvoting with an appropriate reason is more or less sending a good message.

Comment: I see this fairly regularly, though usually the downvote is not immediately after my comment (which may or may not have included a downvote) but occurs a few hours later.  And the last time this happened (about 4 days ago) I was downvoted on two totally unrelated answers I'd posted **on the same day in November**.

Comment: make it mandatory to provide a comment when you downvote. No comment, no downvote. I don't know why SO can't implement it. Next time, I am going to downvote you guys because there was too much salt in my food.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

It is a pity some people feel a need to retaliate when they think they know who downvoted them; not everyone appreciates feedback!

Do *keep* giving feedback on downvoted posts, in the long run you'll win out; such behaviour happens but is not that common, luckily.

If anyone tries to downvote *a series* of your posts, then their downvotes will be reverted automatically by the [nightly serial voting reversal script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me); voting should target content, not users, after all.

Comment: hmm. I don't understand why users are getting annoyed because of getting downvotes when there is a valid reason.  This is a place where we can learn something from our mistakes right?

Comment: @Praveen: not everyone is mature enough to understand that.

Comment: I wonder if anyone has ever created a secondary account who's sole purpose is to comment for a downvote left by the main account. That secondary account could get to 50 rep using edits. That way the secondary account would have no posts for a retaliating user to downvote.

Comment: @Mysticial: I should totally create *Martijn's downvote ninja* right now! People will never know its me! :-P

Comment: @Mysticial great scenario.  But  will it really happen..? thinking.. thinking..

Comment: @Praveen It's totally doable. It circumvents a deficiency in the current system that doesn't let you comment anonymously. I won't speak for whether it's allowed though. But I definitely wouldn't call it voting fraud. You're still casting one vote.

Comment: I've had points reinstated that were removed by a serial downvoter. It also works in reverse - serial upvoting will also be corrected!

Comment: [Just had this happen to me.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23187021/css-selector-for-all-non-input-fields/23190578#23190578) I ain't even mad, but I can't begin to comprehend how some people *live* with knowing they couldn't justify their retaliatory downvotes by anything other than pique.

Comment: @BoltClock: I can only imagine how much more diamond moderators must experience this kind of response, though. :-)

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: To be honest, not all that much - thanks to the fact that you need 125 rep to cast downvotes :)

Comment: I'm thankfull someone finally commented on my downvoted answer. Now I understand what I did wrong and I can do better in the future! So thank you to everyone who does give comments on downvotes.

Comment: What if a comment was actually *required* to accompany a downvote, but the downvoter has the option of remaining anonymous?

Comment: @Booboo That has already been proposed, and is also not without issues: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/407716

Answer (score 13):

The answer is the question. What does a commentless downvote achieve? Makes a post you don't like for some reason, drop down the stack and perhaps ensures its closure/ deletion. Other than that, nothing. Personally I think downvote without a comment should cost more reputation points than an anonymous one. There are way too many people on here more concerned with punishing bad answers or worse still 'bad' questions, than learning or teaching. We've got to manage the questions somehow, but if we keep going the way we are, people will come here to earn a reputation, instead of coming here and earning a reputation.

So my answer is you should reserve just downvoting, for absolute garbage, like help it doesn't work or how do I hack my girlfriend's email account.

Answer (score -9):

It's too bad there isn't a vote delay timer on new posts to prevent fly-bys.
Something based on how long you've been on the that particular post and its length - e.g. a 2 line post 10 seconds, a 5 paragraph post a minute.
Maybe it's not practical but it makes you less inclined to participate on this board when you feel that your posts are being downvoted either arbitrarily or because you angered a power player.

I've had a new question downvoted before it was even 10 seconds old - not enough time to read the post let alone consider its merit. 
So it was either voted down purely because of the title or as a spite move.

Edited: The case I was referring to was in regards to posting new question, not a reply to question.  Edited post to clarify that.

Comment: It is often possible to tell in under 10 seconds that a post fails to answer the question.  It is often possible to tell in under 10 seconds that the code in a post doesn't compile, or contains serious bugs.  It is often possible to tell in under 10 seconds that an answer is just completely wrong.  I have certainly downvoted answers in the past, within 10 seconds of first seeing them; and I stand by every one of my downvotes.

Comment: Fails to answer the question - possibly, but to evaluate a new question that contains more than a couple of sentences - no.  Edited my post to clarify that I was actually referring to a post of a new question, not a reply.

Comment: @DavidWallace - in regards to downvoting replies, yes some replies can determined as wrong, out of context, etc. fairly quickly.  I was approaching the issue from the viewpoint of having a new question getting immediately downvoted. When a new post containing a couple of paragraphs of information gets downvoted before it's even 10 seconds old with no comments - I don't believe that the downvote is actually based on the merit of the question or see how it can be viewed as constructive to the poster or the community.

Comment: @TheSteven I can often tell from the title of a question alone that it's a terrible question; poorly researched, frequently duplicated questions, for example, are often discoverable from the title alone.

Comment: @TheSteven I don't care how many paragraphs or lines of code you included.  If your question title is **== doesn't work for strings in Java**, I'm opening the question just to downvote and mark as duplicate without reading a single line of the question body.

Comment: @nhgrif if the goal is to improve the forum and the quality of its content then your approach fails to do either. Perhaps the title is bad or doesn't properly summarize the issue.  Perhaps the user is a nube (or English isn't their main language) then a (helpful) comment would be more beneficial; it would not only help point them in the right direction but also improve their future posts. Granted there are posts that deserve to be down voted and often the title can be an indicator of the quality of the post but as the sole judging factor? Consider the saying about judging a book by it's cover.

Comment: Of course, to a busy and possibly frustrated programmer leaving a comment is more time consuming and lacks the satisfaction & anonymity  (and points?) that slapping a down vote gives.

Comment: @TheSteven Perhaps you're unfamiliar with how frequently this particular Java question is asked.  Moreover, the duplicate close vote comment automatically leaves a comment--a link to the question they clearly couldn't bother to look at before posting theirs.  I'm not suggesting that I never leave comments, but certainly there are times that I've downvoted **and posted a close vote** without necessarily leaving a comment.  The close vote is comment enough.

Comment: Moreover, posting a comment to someone's question that will obviously be closed sometimes tends to lead into a pointless argument in the comment section *as it has in the recent past with a **== doesn't work for strings in Java*** question.