# I don't know isn't a bug or someone did?

Tags: discussion

After I downvoted to someone question , as soon as I went to look my reputation in profile and I found out that I got so many downvote ! I wonder it is a *bug* as I downvoted on someone question ? But if someone actually downvoted to me , no problem !!

[image]

Comment: Not a bug, those are likely revenge downvotes and they will get reverted automatically.

Comment: wait for 24 hrs atleast. The system should revert it. Welcome to the club

Comment: Related: [What can I do about getting a sudden flood of revenge downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252270/what-can-i-do-about-getting-a-sudden-flood-of-revenge-downvotes)

Comment: Looks like you've got a fan. As mentioned they'll all get reversed at ~3am... so don't worry about it :)

Comment: "After I downvoted to someone question" – Related: [Should I comment or just downvote?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251299/2564301) and [Why isn't providing feedback mandatory on downvotes, and why are ideas suggesting such shot down?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357436/2564301). Your – bad – experience is a good answer to the latter.